# Can I launch Xcode 4 Application from Xcode3.2

Tags: osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard, xcode4.3, xcode3.2

Consider an Application developed on Xcode 4.3 in lion and have lion's apis in that application.
I have another application which is running on Xcode 3.2 in snow leopard.Can I launch the Xcode 4 application from Xcode 3.2 from the Snow Leopard.I think we need to take care of deprecated api.
Do I need to take care of any other precautions apart from the deprecated apis.

Comment: did you mean the Xcode Version or the iOS SDK Version?